# Error Curl error: No URL set! al introducir datos en bbdd a través de una api

Tags: php, curl

Estoy realizando un ejercicio e el que pretendo crear actividades usando una api y guardarlas en la bbdd.

No consigo guardar las actividades en la bbdd.

Haciendo var_dump del json veo que la actividad esta bien pasada.

En este caso he hallado que el error de produce en el curl_init(), que me devuelve : Curl error: No URL set!
No he encontrado mucha info acerca de este error y la poca que hay es toda antigua.

El endpoint es correcto ya que lo etoy usando para mostrar las actividades ya creadas.

El código de la función :

```
function crearActividad($actividad)
{
    //definimos a dónde nos vamos a conectar
    $endpoint = "http://localhost/DAES/UF4/ACTIVIDAD/API/index.php";
    $json = json_encode($actividad);
    echo var_dump($json);
    //inicializamos el curl
    $curl = curl_init();
    if (curl_exec($curl) === false) {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    } else {
        echo 'Operación completada sin errores';
    }
    //le configuramos la url a la que se va a conectar, alojada en la var $endpoint
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    
    //esta opción chequea que si todo va bien devuelva 1
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    //le decimos que le vamos a pasar la info a través del POST
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    //le decimos que los datos van a ser en formato json
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    //le pasamos los datos en json a partir de la encodificación de $actividad
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);

    //ejecutamos petición
    curl_exec($curl);
    if (curl_exec($curl) === false) {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    }
    //cerramos la petición
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

Código de la función en la api:

```
function crearActividad()
{
    $actividad = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $usuario=$_SESSION["usuario"]["Id"];

    global $conexion_mysql;

    // SQL
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO actividades (titulo, fecha, ciudad, tipo, coste, usuario) 
                 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    // Creamos sentencia preparada
    $stmt = $conexion_mysql->prepare($consulta);
    // Comprobamos que este bien la sentencia preparada
    if (!$stmt) {
        exit('Sentencia prepare() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars(($conexion_mysql->prepare($consulta))->error_));
    }

    $resultado = $stmt->bind_param(
        'ssssds',

        $actividad["titulo"],
        $actividad["fecha"],
        $actividad["ciudad"],
        $actividad["tipo"],
        $actividad["coste"],
        $usuario
    );
    
    // Comprobamos que este bien los tipos y variables en nuestro bind.
    if (!$resultado) {
        exit('bind_param() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    // Ejecutamos resultado
    $resultado = $stmt->execute();
    // Comprobamos que se haya ejecutado correctamente
    if (!$resultado) {
        exit('execute() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    if ($resultado) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    } else {
        header("HTTP/1.1 500Internal Server Error");
    }
}
```

Qué se me está escapando?

Answer (score 1):

Estás haciendo un `curl_exec` justo después de `curl_init` sin haberle pasado pasado parámetro URL.

Veo que utlizas `CURLOPT_URL`, por lo que usar `curl_init` sin parámetro estaría bien.

También veo que haces otro `curl_exec` más adelante, después de asignar todas las opciones a curl. Por lo que creo que te está sobrando por completo el primer `curl_exec` que haces, quizás has copiado y pegado desde otro lado, y te lo has dejado ahí por error durante el desarrollo.

Prueba a quitar ese trozo por completo:

```
//inicializamos el curl
$curl = curl_init();
/* ESTO SOBRA if (curl_exec($curl) === false) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
} else {
    echo 'Operación completada sin errores';
}*/
//le configuramos la url a la que se va a conectar, alojada en la var $endpoint
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
```

Con eso tendrías solucionado el problema concreto por el que preguntas. Pero, además, en el `curl_exec` que haces más adelante, lo estás haciendo dos veces, una tal cual y otra comprobando el resultado. Te sobraría la de tal cual:

```
//ejecutamos petición
/* ESTO SOBRA: curl_exec($curl); */
if (curl_exec($curl) === false) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
```

En cualquier caso, aún solucionando esos dos puntos, puede que no te llegue a funcionar bien. Creo que no estás pasando bien los datos de la actividad a la API.

Comment: he colocado ese if porque es como he entendido que debía gestionarlo en caso de error según el manual de php. Si lo quito, no me devuelve el error `Curl error: No URL set! ` , pero tampoco me guarda la actividad.

Comment: Ese `if` con `curl_exec` ahí no pinta nada, y es la causa del error por el que has preguntado. El que luego no te guarde la actividad es porque tendrás más fallos. Creo que estás pasando mal los datos de la actividad a la API.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP, buena respuesta; solo falta corregir la parte final, donde ejecuta dos veces, una _"normal"_ y otra dentro del `if`. Creo que eso resolvería el problema.